# Конвертация html в pdf c помощью MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Нарисовал страницу отчета по сотруднику на html с php-вставками кода. При конвертации с помощью MPDF, все, что на php, выводит текстом. Можно ли это исправить? Переделывать на html в лом, слишком долго возился с шаблоном, плюс переменные берутся из сессий не знаю, как их реализовывать на html.

Comment: Ну он же не будет за вас шаблоны исполнять. Quick'n'dirty - обернуть шаблоны в буфер и выполнить их, но вообще нужно просто использовать шаблонизатор.

Comment: Исправил. Я не использовал шаблоны. По-сути я просто нарисовал html страницу(отчет по сотруднику) и мне её нужно перевести в PDF

Comment: HTML со вставками еи есть то, что я назвал шаблоном.

Comment: Тогда объясните на пальцах, как обернуть их, и что такое шаблонизатор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> При конвертации с помощью MPDF, все, что на php, выводит текстом.

PHP *исполняется*. Это значит, что пока его принудительно не прогнали через интерпретатор, он и будет так выглядеть. С учетом того, что у вас за спиной полушаблона явно присутствует массивный контекст (сессия, переменные и прочее), проще все будет забуферизовать вывод:

```
ob_start(); // начало буферизации
include '/some/file.php';
$contents = ob_get_clean(); // конец буферизации и получение записанного в буфер.
```

Все, что будет выведено между вызовами `ob_start();` и `ob_get_clean();` будет записано в буфер и впоследствии опрокинуто в `$contents`. Подробнее можно прочитать в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.outcontrol.php).

> что такое шаблонизатор?

Это *нормальное* решение для создание шаблонизированного вывода. Вы уже столкнулись с тем, что шаблон "не вынуть" из приложения, потому что он намертво завязан на окружение, и чтобы получить результат, его надо скормить интерпретатору. Шаблонизатор же является библиотекой, которой берет на себя эту задачу: на вход подается шаблон и контекст, и шаблонизатор заполняет шаблон согласно контексту, возвращая результат в переменной. Явный лидер на PHP - [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org).

Answer (score 0):

Пишете на MPDF простенький скриптик, который принимает ввод из STDIN. И сохраняет в файле с именем из аргументов. Кладёте вашу страницу на сервер. И:

`wget -o /dev/null -O - http://страница/ | ваш_скрипт страница.pdf`

Таким же образом, используя wget в режиме паука, можно сконвертировать хоть целый сайт (при условии наличия перекрёстных ссылок на страницах).

Правда, возникает вопрос: зачем тогда MPDF?

Comment: На MPDF можно писать скрипты?Что такое STDIN?wget в режиме паука? Я слаб в программировании) Можно обо всем этом поподробнее, а луче другой способ.

Comment: Скрипты можно писать на PHP. С использованием библиотеки MPDF. "*Я слаб в программировании*" - вот и потренируетесь. А другие способы - на других сайтах...